# Error while installing Py.test via macports

Tags: python, macos, macports, pytest

I'm trying to install [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/) via macports, after installing `py.test --version` gives me an error:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: py>=1.4.12
```

What is "py"?

UPD:

```
which -a python : 

/opt/local/bin/python 
/usr/bin/python 
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

which py.test :

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/py.test
```

Comment: Is there an ulterior motive for running `py.test --version`? Or is that what macports is doing during the installation?

Comment: @Spen-ZAR the installation goes fine.  I just can't run py.test

Comment: What command did you use to install it? Was it `sudo port install py-pytest`? I like to be specific and choose the Python distribution I'm working with, doing something like `sudo port install py27-pytest`.

Comment: The reason I'm saying this is because maybe the `python` version wasn't selected in MacPorts prior to installation. I don't have a Mac here, so I can't test this right now.

Comment: @Spen-ZAR Yeah, I did `py27-pytest` too. and I have python27 selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, it turned out I didn't have py lib installed itself. so I just did: `sudo port install py27-py`, Somehow I thought MacPorts also installs all the libs a package needs.

Answer (score 1):

py is the pytest package, and it probably means that the location macports installed the package isn't the same location as your `/usr/bin/env python` site-packages but the `py.test` script is in your path. You can look to change your shell path to use the macports python. Or you can install the pytest package in your default python environment. 
Try:

```
which -a python
which py.test
```

The easiest way to install python packages is using the python package installer `pip install pytest`. This will put it in the right environment.
You could also explore virtualenv if you only want it for a specific project.

Comment: I remembered having to set the Python path first. It was annoying at first, but working with MacPorts is quite wonderful after that.

Comment: ``for i in `which -a python`; do $i -c 'import py' 2> /dev/null || { echo -n "Not "; };  echo "In $i"; done`` to find out which python macports install pytest into.

Comment: I guess pip will build an extra python library in my home dir, I'd like to stick with macports, as long as it has a package I need.

Comment: pip by default will put it in your site-pacakges, you may need to do `sudo pip install pytest` if that is not writeable by the user, much like `sudo port install pytest`. pip relies on your environment to place the package in the right site-packages. port just puts it in a specific python distribution.

Comment: I am a big advocate of virtualenv, and pip would be the only way to go. I like to not pollute the system site-packages for specific packages for a project. General purpose packages I'll push up to the system site-packages.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I got a little familiar with $PYTHONPATH, virtualenv and pip. ;)